# JavaFX: How can you get setCellValueFactory to ignore empty items in an ObservableArray?

Tags: java, javafx, observablelist

I'm new to java and don't fully understand the structure of Javafx, so I'm getting lost in the weeds here.

It's an inventory management app for a course I'm taking.

I have two classes that are inheriting from an abstract class, and an ObservableList that holds instances of both the child classes.  Now, when I try to display both classes together in TableView with a cellvaluefactory, I get errors due to the missing attributes from one or the other.  The program compiles but the warnings are due to fields "missing" from whichever field is missing from it's respective instance.  (PartOutsourced is missing the "machineId" field, and PartInhouse is missing the "companyName" field.

[UI picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7N8T.png)

I know there must be some way to get the cellValueFactory to ignore the null values or fill them with empty strings, but I have no idea how, and google has been a dead end.

Here are the two child classes:

```
public class PartOutsourced extends Part {
    private String companyName;

    public PartOutsourced(String name, int stock, double price, int min, int max, String companyName) {
        super(name, stock, price, min, max);
        this.companyName = companyName;
    }

    public String getCompanyName() {
        return companyName;
    }

    public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
    }
}
```

```
public class PartInHouse extends Part {
    private int machineId;

    public PartInHouse(String name, int stock, double price, int min, int max, int machineId) {
        super(name, stock, price, min, max);
        this.machineId = machineId;
    }

    public int getMachineId() {
        return machineId;
    }

    public void setMachineId(int machineId) {
        this.machineId = machineId;
    }
}
```

Here is the cellValueFactory code:

```
        col_id.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Part, String>("id"));
        col_name.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Part, String>("name"));
        col_stock.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Part, String>("stock"));
        col_price.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Part, String>("price"));
        col_min.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Part, String>("min"));
        col_max.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Part, String>("max"));
        col_machine_id.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Part, String>("machineId"));
        col_company.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Part, String>("companyName"));
```

A bit of the the stacktrace:

```
May 14, 2020 12:14:06 PM javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory getCellDataReflectively
WARNING: Can not retrieve property 'machineId' in PropertyValueFactory: javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory@5f88bef3 with provided class type: class inventory.datamodel.PartOutsourced
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot read from unreadable property machineId
```

Comment: For the inheritance to work, all the methods that matter should be in the abstract class. This way the individual subclasses can return the proper value for your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your own implementation of the `Callback` (e.g. using lambdas) instead of the `PropertyValueFactory` (this is generally recommended anyway; `PropertyValueFactory` was really only written as a placeholder before lambda expression were introduced, since implementing the `Callback` with an inner class was very verbose). Then you can return the property you need (e.g. an `IntegerProperty` wrapping the value) if the object is the right type, or a property wrapping null (e.g. an `ObjectProperty<Number>`) if not.

Since your `machineId` is a `Number`, you should use

```
private TableColumn<Part, Number> col_machine_id ; // note: please use proper Java naming conventions
```

and then you can do

```
col_machine_id.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> {
    Part part = cellData.getValue() ;
    if (part instanceof PartInHouse) {
        return new SimpleIntegerProperty(((PartInHouse)part).getMachineId());
    }
    return new SimpleObjectProperty<>(null);
});
```

Note that it's also recommended to use JavaFX properties in your model class:

```
public class PartInHouse extends Part {
    private final IntegerProperty machineId = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

    public PartInHouse(String name, int stock, double price, int min, int max, int machineId) {
        super(name, stock, price, min, max);
        setMachineId(machineId);
    }

    public IntegerProperty machineIdProperty() {
        return machineId ;
    }

    public final int getMachineId() {
        return machineIdProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setMachineId(int machineId) {
        machineIdProperty().set(machineId);
    }
}
```

in which case you can use the following cell value factory:

```
col_machine_id.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> {
    Part part = cellData.getValue() ;
    if (part instanceof PartInHouse) {
        return ((PartInHouse)part).machineIdProperty();
    }
    return new SimpleObjectProperty<>(null);
});
```

Here's a complete running example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class InheritanceTableModelTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        TableView<Part> table = new TableView<>();
        for (int i = 1 ; i <= 20 ; i++) {
            table.getItems().add(new PartInHouse("Part "+(2*i), i));
            table.getItems().add(new PartOutsourced("Part "+(2*i+1), "Company "+i));
        }
        TableColumn<Part, String> nameCol = new TableColumn<>("Part");
        TableColumn<Part, Number> machineIdCol = new TableColumn<>("Machine ID");
        TableColumn<Part, String> companyCol = new TableColumn<>("Company");

        nameCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().nameProperty());
        machineIdCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> {
            Part part = cellData.getValue();
            if (part instanceof PartInHouse) {
                return ((PartInHouse)part).machineIdProperty();
            }
            return new SimpleObjectProperty<>(null);
        });
        companyCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> {
            Part part = cellData.getValue();
            if (part instanceof PartOutsourced) {
                return ((PartOutsourced)part).companyNameProperty();
            }
            return new SimpleObjectProperty<>(null);
        });

        table.getColumns().add(nameCol);
        table.getColumns().add(machineIdCol);
        table.getColumns().add(companyCol);

        Scene scene = new Scene(new BorderPane(table));
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static class Part {
        private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
        public Part(String name) {
            setName(name);
        }
        public StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return name;
        }
        public final String getName() {
            return nameProperty().get();
        }
        public final void setName(String name) {
            nameProperty().set(name);
        }
    }

    public static class PartInHouse extends Part {
        private final IntegerProperty machineId = new SimpleIntegerProperty() ;
        public PartInHouse(String name, int machineId) {
            super(name);
            setMachineId(machineId);
        }
        public IntegerProperty machineIdProperty() {
            return machineId ;
        }
        public int getMachineId() {
            return machineIdProperty().get();
        }
        public void setMachineId(int machineId) {
            machineIdProperty().set(machineId);
        }
    }

    public static class PartOutsourced extends Part {
        private final StringProperty companyName = new SimpleStringProperty();

        public PartOutsourced(String name, String companyName) {
            super(name);
            setCompanyName(companyName);
        }

        public StringProperty companyNameProperty() {
            return companyName ;
        }

        public String getCompanyName() {
            return companyNameProperty().get();
        }

        public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
            companyNameProperty().set(companyName);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response.  This did work well.  Some of your exact methodology is still a bit over my head (lots to learn about java) but this got it working.